# List to Map giving compilation error

Tags: collections, java-8, guava

I have the following code :

```
List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();

//Object is actually a Map<String,Object>

return Maps.uniqueIndex(result, new Function<Map<String, Object>, Long>() {
            @Override
            public Long apply(Map<String, Object> input) {
                return (Long) input.remove("id");
            }
        });
```

I get compilation error.

> The method `uniqueIndex(Iterable<V>, Function<? super V,K>)` in the type Maps is not applicable for the arguments `(List, new Function<Map<String,Object>,Long>(){})`.

How do I rewrite this piece of code such that I don't get into this issue?

Comment: what is that code *supposed* to do, it does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: convert list to map and filter the list.

Comment: that is still unclear. Please show examples of input + output.

Comment: Btw the biggest no-no I see here is the cast from Object to Long and a `List<Object` which apparently only contains `Long`s but is not typed in a way that would make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

The first generic parameter of `Function` must match the type of elements held by `List`.

So, if you have a `List<T>`, a `Function` will be used for doing something with elements from that `List`, hence it needs to be a `Function<T, WHATEVER>`.

So, in your case:

```
List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();

Maps.uniqueIndex(result, new Function<Object, WHATEVER>() {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public WHATEVER apply(@Nullable Object s) {
        return null; // do whatever you want here
    }
});
```

---

If you want to store `Map<String,Object>` in a `List` why not use `List<Map<String,Object>>`?

```
List<Map<String,Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();

Maps.uniqueIndex(result, new Function<Map<String,Object>, WHATEVER>() {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public WHATEVER apply(@Nullable Map<String,Object> s) {
        return null; // do whatever you want here
    }
});
```